# Do we have failed transactions in bitcoin?

Tags: transactions, mining-pools

I was checking the failed transactions and gas used in Ethereum: https://blockchair.com/ethereum/transactions?q=failed(true)

Do we have similar transactions in bitcoin that I can compare with?

Answer (score 1):

No, a bitcoin script has to evaluate to true to be spendable.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script