# Comparing UTXO transactions with Accounts transactions

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, utxo

I have seen few websites that compare number of transactions and fees between Bitcoin and Ethereum.

Examples: https://www.flippening.watch/ and https://cryptofees.info/

What does the high number of transactions and fees indicate for a network in this comparison? Does it mean one is used more and better than other?

Answer (score 2):

1. The only thing which Ethereum community or other altcoins community does better is **marketing**. I won't even consider it better or sometimes consider scammers or frauds or people trying to **spread misinformation**. I have never seen such hatred and misinformation being spread in any industry about something like Bitcoin which is the biggest reason why all this exists.
2. There are few **related questions** that have highlighted the difference in UTXO and accounts in past:

   [UTXO model vs. account/balance model](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49853/utxo-model-vs-account-balance-model)

   [Why is there "Change" in Bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96822/why-is-there-change-in-bitcoins)
3. https://cryptofees.info/ uses CoinMetrics according to the footer of website. Coinmetrics has mentioned in a post that you **cannot compare transactions** of UTXO chains with Accounts based chains:

> The third column is txCount. That refers to the number of transactions happening on the public blockchain a day. Be aware that for low-fee blockchains, it’s really easy to fabricate a whole bunch of transactions. So this isn’t necessarily that reliable! Additionally, **UTXO networks like Bitcoin can batch a whole bunch of transactions into one**, so txCount underestimates those ones. You have to therefore be careful comparing the number of transactions on Ethereum with Bitcoin; by its very nature, Bitcoin typically has more transactions than that datapoint suggests. Naively comparing the UTXO to account based systems by transaction count is like watching motorway traffic and comparing the number of buses versus motorcycles to guess at how many people are making trips. Maybe there are the same number of buses and motorcycles – but each bus might have 50 people inside of it.

https://coinmetrics.io/on-data-and-certainty/

Mean transaction fee for Bitcoin and Ethereum according to Coinmetrics:

[image: mean-tx-fees]

4. **Outputs per day in Bitcoin**:

[image: Outputs-Per-Day]
https://bitcoinvisuals.com/chain-output-count-day

You can also check: https://transactionfee.info/charts/payments-per-day/ (*The payments metric counts the number of outputs a transaction has and subtracts one to exclude the change output. If a transaction has only one output, then it’s counted as one payment. The purpose of this metric is to provide a more accurate representation of real economic activity on the Bitcoin network.*)

5. There are lot of other differences and its difficult to compare but things that one should consider while responding to marketing trolls:

   Bitcoin doesn't have **failed transactions** involving any fees: [Do we have failed transactions in bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/101103/do-we-have-failed-transactions-in-bitcoin)

   **[Blocksize](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/99713/) and Transaction Size** (the answers are not updated and gas limit has increased): https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/is-there-a-limit-for-transaction-size/

   Bitcoin has max 1.5-2MB of block per 10 minutes on an average

   Bitcoin transactions and size: https://twitter.com/murchandamus/status/1262062602298916865
6. You need smart contracts for batching in Ethereum according to below links:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/71271/

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/84064/

Lets consider if Bitcoin had no batching and I had to somehow send BTC to multiple people:

[3f99102c76af2ecfe7c7da826cbefd8a5d4465ac2c63e88a975df89b23c8bf5d](https://btc.bitaps.com/3f99102c76af2ecfe7c7da826cbefd8a5d4465ac2c63e88a975df89b23c8bf5d) has 1 input and 5 outputs

Size for each input and output involved in tx

```
Input: 91 vB

   Output 1: 32 B 
   Output 2: 32B
   Output 3: 32 B
   Output 4: 31 B
   Output 5: 32 B

   Size of original tx: 344 / 235 bytes 
   Virtual size / weight: 263 / 1049

   Fee for original tx: 0.00019 BTC
```

If you create 5 transactions to use one input and different outputs mentioned in above tweet, 91*4=360vB extra will be required or maybe more.

If same fee rate is used (73 sat/vB), 0.00026 BTC extra fee will have to paid

**SO YOU PAY DOUBLE FEE FOR DOING THE SAME THING and 5x transactions!**

One of the reasons batching is used by lot of people in Bitcoin: https://bitcointechtalk.com/saving-up-to-80-on-bitcoin-transaction-fees-by-batching-payments-4147ab7009fb

7. Bitcoin has few **layer 2 solutions** that are used and thousands of on-chain transactions have moved to off-chain. I couldn't find a website that could show approximate transactions and not even sure if its possible to do it for LN, but below links have related information:

   http://bitcoinkpis.com/layer2

   https://bitcoin.clarkmoody.com/dashboard/

   https://1ml.com/statistics

Comment: Oh man, there's a lot of inaccuracies here. The main one I'll point out is that your CoinMetrics quote states _"You have to therefore be careful comparing the number of transactions on Ethereum with Bitcoin"_. That's not relevant to the original question re: cryptofees.info, which compares blockchains by _fee revenue_, not by transaction count.

Comment: If the number of transactions are more in a given time frame and average fee is almost same per transaction or more, total fees will obviously be more.

Comment: Average fees are not the same for Bitcoin & Ethereum transactions. It's also an apples & oranges comparison, since Ethereum transactions can be much more complex than Bitcoin transactions (DEX swaps, lending, contract deployments, ZK proof validation, rollup data dumps). cryptofees.info compares _total fees_, regardless of the number of transactions or the average transaction fee.

Comment: BTC tx fees mean (USD): `11` ETH tx fees mean (USD): `16` If you think its apples and oranges comparison, the website should have just focused on Ethereum fees or Ethereum smart contracts or have enough information of things listed including Bitcoin. The message on top: _Which ones are people actually paying to use?_ is misleading and I had mentioned the exception in my tweet thread: https://twitter.com/prayankgahlot/status/1346325673829404673 even though 1 Bitcoin tx can be done for many things including Atomic swaps, DLC, LN channels, Coinjoin, Timestamps, Sidechain peg-in, peg-out etc.,